# Determine template type from local variable set by non compile-time constants?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, types, generic-programming

I am making a transpiler from Scheme to C++, and part of this is converting a string type from "car" (a Scheme function I implemented in C++) to its actual type - I am deducing this via Regex. My problem is that my function must return different types depending on the nature of the input string. I have attempted to solve this by defining the return value by the function's template name, but since its eventual value isn't a compile time constant, how can I make this possible?

```cpp
// determine_type.cpp

#include <regex>
#include "example_3.cpp"

std::string INT_REGEX = "^[-+]?\\d+$",
            DOUBLE_REGEX = "^[-+]?\\d+\\.\\d?$",
            BOOLEAN_REGEX = "^(true|false)$";

bool matchRegex(std::string pattern, std::string inputString) {
    std::regex expression(pattern);
    return std::regex_match(inputString, expression);
}

template <typename T>
T convertVarType(std::string var) {
    T returnVal;

    if (var[0] == '(' && var.back() == ')')
        returnVal = var; // list
    else if (matchRegex(INT_REGEX, var))
        returnVal = std::stoi(var);
    else if (matchRegex(DOUBLE_REGEX, var))
        returnVal = std::stod(var);
    else if (matchRegex(BOOLEAN_REGEX, var))
        returnVal = (var == "true");
    else
        returnVal = var; // string or variable

    return returnVal;
}

int main() {
    std::string expression = "(define x (+ 5 3 (* 2 2)))";
    std::string firstElement = car(expression); // yields "define", from another file
    auto firstVar = convertVarType(firstElement);
    // std::string firstVar = convertVarType(firstElement); // doesn't work either
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have XY problem, you cannot change result type of template function  based on runtime information. One of the possible solution is to use `std::variant` with possible types.

Comment: To roll your own dispatching mechanism, you switch on the runtime value and create differently typed variables in the switch cases.

Comment: @PasserBy that's exactly what I'm doing

Comment: No, you're trying to assign to the same variable, with the __same type__.